# How to treat child element as separate from it's parent in html

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose i have a div tag with id "childDv" and it's parent div with id "parentDv". On clicking ChildDv i have some function call and on click of ParentDv i have some other function call. The problem is, On clicking ChildDv the "parentDv" function also getting called..!! How can i avoid it?

Actual Example:

```
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="@child.ItemType@child.LiveID" onclick="Expand_Now(this)">
                    <span align="right"></span><span class="ic-folder" onclick="menuOpen(this)"></span>
                    <span style="margin-left: 5px!important;">@child.ItemName</span>
                </a>
```

In this scenario, on clicking span element, "menuOpen" is calling as well as "Expand_Now" is also getting called. I don't want it (Expand_Now) to be called.Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Yes, Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: It would be easier by knowing actually what menuOpen and Expand_Now are looking like... But anyway I think what you're looking for is "event.stopPropagation" in menuOpen

Comment: I got the answer from a original question. And you are right, i was looking or "event.stopPropagation" in my menuOpen function.